# Unable to push GCR Image as another image name in same repository

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am trying to push same image in Google Container Registry with different image name in same repository. I am using docker-credential-gcr commands in Jenkins job. I am getting error

```
*denied: An error occurred uploading the manifest with digest*
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more information? How are you using using docker-credential-gcr?

Also, feel free to reach out to the GCR team for help debugging.
Contact info is at the bottom of this page:

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/troubleshooting

Comment: I used instead docker login _json-key option

Comment: This isn't an answer in any meaningful sense.